# Custom Thumbnails on Vimeo Fail to Set to Active Status using API

Tags: thumbnails, vimeo-api

I've been stuck for days.  Vimeo video and thumbnail uploads, returns that it was set to "active" successfully but then the auto-generated thumbnail is active.

I tried several different versions where the thumbnail uploads and sets to active status (apparently).  Then after transcoding is complete the auto-generated thumbnail is the active one.

I ran another code separately to change the status of the thumbnail after transcoding was complete and this is the response: (I checked the videos and thumbnail on Vimeo myself to verify the thumbnails were there).

Thumbnail Status Response: {"error":"The user isn't allowed to perform that action."}
Thumbnail Status Data: {'error': "The user isn't allowed to perform that action."}
Thumbnail transcoding failed or is still in progress
Thumbnail Status Response: {"error":"The user isn't allowed to perform that action."}
Thumbnail Status Data: {'error': "The user isn't allowed to perform that action."}
Thumbnail transcoding failed or is still in progress

I have a ticket in with Vimeo but I thought I'd ask here in case someone has any idea what I can do to fix it or has run into this problem before.

I'm using Python with VS Code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from Vimeo and it was a simple boolean error:

```
payload = {'active': 'true'}
response = requests.patch(set_thumbnail_active_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I believe I had 'True'.

In addition, they gave me header information for Thumbnails:

```
thumb_headers = {
"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
"Content-Type": "image/jpg",
"Accept": "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json" 
 }
 response = requests.put(upload_link, headers=thumb_headers, data=image_data)
```